# Getting error while editing record inspite of having Modify All permission on an object

Tags: permissions, profile

I have an api user who has **modify all** permission on Asset object under his profile but when he is trying to edit asset he is getting below error.

> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

Comment: Do they have field level access to what they are changing as well?  Do you have a Trigger helper method that you accidentally put the **with sharing*8 keyword on?

Comment: I see they have an access to some of the fields on the pagelayout but not all fields .. will it affect the editibilty..There is no with sharing keyword on handler class

Comment: If the access is just restricted on the PageLayout it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The user is tied to a Salesforce (internal) license type, and not an external license type of some sort?

Comment: user is tied to internal license type (Salesforce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by giving Modify All permission on Account.